When can we apply conservation of momentum?
This question really plagued my mind, and it really struck me when i was trying to solve the following problem


A frictionless inclined plane terminates smoothly into a frictionless vertical circular loop mounted on a plank that can slide on a frictionless horizontal floor. This assembly has a total mass of 0.8 kg. A small ball $P$ of mass 0.2 kg is released on the inclined plane from a height that is triple of the radius of the circular loop. Find the force of normal reaction between the ball and the circular loop, when the ball is at its topmost position in the circular loop.

To solve the problem i considered the velocity of the small ball to be $v_1$ to wards the left at the top and the velocity of the assembly $v_2$ towards the right, relative to the the loop i came up with the following equation considered mass of small ball to be $m$.
$$N + mg = \frac{m(v_1 + v_2)^2}{r}$$
Also energy conservation gave me the following equation
$$mgr = \frac{1}{2}mv_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}Mv_2^2$$
The only issue now to solve these two equations that i faced was that i could not relate $v_1$ and $v_2$, and after thinking for some time, and not being able to come up with a relation i looked at the solution which related the velocities as follows
$$mv_1 = Mv_2$$
Where $M$ is the mass of the assembly.
Doing so and using my equations i can match my answers with the book however, i do not understand how can we apply conservation of momentum, as conservation of momentum is only applicable when their is no external force on the system, but their is clearly an external force on the system which is gravity!.
I do not understand what is wrong with my logic, could someone please concretely explain to me when and when not can we apply conservation of momentum.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

The conservation of momentum is valid in separate axes. So, since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are both in the horizontal axis, and there is no external force (gravitational force acts in the vertical direction) in the horizontal axis, conservation of momentum can be applied, even though momentum may not be conserved in the vertical direction.

Thanks for the answers, understood my mistake now
